# K-theory for non-separable C*-algebras

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, topological-k-theory, k-theory

Let $\kappa$ be an uncountable cardinal. What is the K-theory for the C*-algebras $\mathcal{K}(\ell_2(\kappa))$ and $\mathcal{B}(\ell_2(\kappa))$, of, respectively, compact and bounded operators on $\ell_2(\kappa)$?

Answer (score 3):

For every Hilbert space $H$, $$K_0(\mathcal{K}(H))=\mathbb{Z}$$ because the only compact projections in $\mathcal{B}(H^{\oplus n})\cong M_n(\mathcal{B}(H))$ are finite-rank projections and these are distinguished only by dimension. Actually $$K_0(\mathcal{K}(E)) = \mathbb{Z}$$ for any Banach space $E$. Moreover, if $H$ is infinite-dimensional then $$K_0(\mathcal{B}(H))=\{0\},$$
because $H\cong H\oplus H$, hence $[{\rm id}_H]\oplus [{\rm id}_H] = [{\rm id}_H]$ so it must be the trivial group.

As Atkinson's theorem works well in non-separable spaces, the $K_1$-groups are the same as for the separable Hilbert space.

Comment: Can you explain the line: $H \cong H \oplus H$, hence .... in more detail please?

Comment: @QuantumSpace, let $\lambda$ be the density charactrer of $H$. We have $H\cong \ell_2(\lambda)$, as $H$ is infinite-dimensional, so decompose $\lambda$ into two sets of the same cardinality $\lambda$, $A$ and $B$ say. Then $H \cong \ell_2(A)\oplus \ell_2(B)\cong H\oplus H$.

Comment: Thanks. I actually meant the remainder of the sentence.

Comment: I would also be interested to understand the implication $H\cong H\oplus H \Rightarrow [Id_H]\oplus[Id_H]= [Id_H]$, could somebody please elaborate?

Comment: The answer is hopefully as follows: all isomorphic vector spaces are also isometric, so $Id_{H\oplus\{0\}} = u Id_{H\oplus H} u^*$ for some unitary $u$. This means $[Id_H] = [Id_{H\oplus H}] = [Id_H]+[Id_H]$.